# Cannot Parse properties from HTTPRequest using Javascript - Homework

Tags: javascript, ajax, bing-api

I am having an issue parsing properties from the response I get to an API call.  I can see the results using a console log, but when I attempt to parse the data and display it, I get "undefined" for all the properties.  I know fetch is a different animal, but this is an assignment and we need to do it with GET requests.  I also know modern JavaScript etiquette doesn't require backwards compatible event listeners, but our book is from 2016.

The relevant JavaScript:

```
function getRequestObject() {
   try {
       httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } catch (requestError) {
       return false;
   }
   return httpRequest;
}

function getResults(evt) {
   if (evt.preventDefault) {
       evt.preventDefault();
   } else {
       evt.returnValue = false;
   }
   var entry = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

   if (!httpRequest) {
       httpRequest = getRequestObject();
   }
   httpRequest.abort();
   httpRequest.open("get", "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(entry) + "&count");
   httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "fb8338ec48d44c2dbc002efd2d065b19");
   httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   httpRequest.send();
   httpRequest.onreadystatechange = displaySuggestions;
}

function displaySuggestions() {
   console.log("display request.response -" + httpRequest.response);
   if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
       // var response = JSON.stringify(httpRequest.response);
       var searchResults = JSON.parse(httpRequest.response);
       console.log("after - search results =" + searchResults);


       console.log(searchResults);

       var articleEl = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
       console.log("name" + searchResults.name);
       for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
           var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
           var head = document.createDocumentFragment();
           var newP1 = document.createElement("p");
           var newP2 = document.createElement("p");
           var newP3 = document.createElement("p");
           var newA = document.createElement("a");
           head.appendChild(newP1);
           newA.innerHTML = searchResults.Title;
           newA.setAttribute("href", searchResults.Url);
           newP1.appendChild(newA);
           newP1.className = "head";
           newP2.innerHTML = searchResults.Url;
           newP2.className = "url";
           newP3.innerHTML = searchResults.Description;
           newDiv.appendChild(head);
           newDiv.appendChild(newP2);
           newDiv.appendChild(newP3);
           articleEl.appendChild(newDiv);
       }
   }
}
```

It is also live on a web server, so here is the url. I am aware of the reference error, it's just a variable that was defined using '`getElementByID`' and the element is not on this particular page.

[Link to live version of page](https://williamsm459/macombserver.net/itwp1100/project5/succulents.html)

Comment: What is the response you are getting? And also, your loop of 20 would only create 20 identical sets of elements...The search result json on your website has no `name` or `Description` properties at the root of the json. There is a `searchResults.webPages.value[0].name` for first result though

Comment: @vanowm

`display request.response -{"_type": "SearchResponse", "queryContext": {"originalQuery": "plants"}, "webPages": {"webSearchUrl": "https:\/\/www.bing.com\/search?q=plants", "totalEstimatedMatches": 36800000, "value": [{"id": "https:\/\/api.bing.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.0", "name": "Order Plants Online - Perennials, Annuals, Shade & Sun ...", "url": "https:\/\/parkseed.com\/plants\/c\/plants\/"` is the beginning of it.  I have just starting learning ajax last week, so I may be missing super simple things.